# Flutter BoxDecoration taking up the whole screen

Tags: flutter

I am trying to place containers with a BoxDecoration. However, when I apply the BoxDecoration to my container to shape the container, it causes the container to take up the whole screen and not just the text that is in the container.

Is there any way I can get the BoxDecoration to only be as big as the text that the container is holding?

```
class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'login_screen';
  const WelcomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('My App'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54, width: 3),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: Column(
            children: const [
              Text(
                'LOGO',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                'Header',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Text(
                  'Strapline Ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black54))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Column` by default tries to be as big as possible

add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `Column`:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [...],
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Your `Container` takes the whole height without your `BoxDecoration` anyway. If you omit your `BoxDecoration` and put a color in your `Container` you will see it doesn't change. If you want the Container to fit your widgets inside it you can use [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html). Just wrap it around your `Container` and set `fit` to [BoxFit.cover](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html).

```
FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54, width: 3),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'LOGO',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Header',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                    'Strapline Ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum lorem ipsum',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black54))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: It's not the container that takes up the space but the column

Comment: thanks for that. The boxfit is good to know about, but the mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min on the column, seemed to fix a lot of problems